# Does ^= create a temporary variable in memory?

Tags: c++, variables, bitwise-operators, xor

Does the bitwise operator `^=` create a temporary variable in memory when it's used?

so for a example if I have:

```
a ^= b;
```

Does it create a copy of `a` in memory, then check against it and then assign? Or does it just straight up check and then assign without creating a temporary variable?

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity or premature optimization?

Comment: Does it matter? Nope...

Comment: The compiler can do either. You cannot observe the difference. Why do you care? Most likely, there is a "temporary", in a sense, in a CPU register rather than in RAM.

Comment: it's defined as `a=a^b` so technically yes, but an implementation is allowed either, under the "as-if rule". The most likely implementation is two load, one xor, one store, so a 'temporary'  in a register

Comment: @IgorTandetnik there doesn't even need to be a temporary *register…* On x86, for example, most binary instructions' destination is one of the operands, e. g. `xor eax, ebx` means `eax = eax xor ebx`, which is implemented in hardware without any loads/stores.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Well, if `a` is initially in RAM, and needs to end up in RAM, then there has to be a load and a store.

Comment: "Also apologies if anything said in this sounds dumb or is wrong." This question is not dumb.I think we should not discourage technical curiosity and at least point to other resources.

Comment: @Mysticial not for premature optimization, mostly because I wanted to check if I was correct with what I though the ^= operator does. Trying to make sure my knowledge is correct basically

Comment: What do you mean by "check"?

Comment: @Matt how things work conceptually in a language and how they are implemented are two very different things, overlapping mostly in the observable effects of larger units of code. That *especially* applies to temporary variables, because you usually can't observe them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a compiler specific question, but I tried it with `g++ -O2` and `clang++ -O2`. It compiled this:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = argc, b = argc * 3;
    a ^= b;
    return a;
}
```

to

```
leal    (%rdi,%rdi,2), %eax
xorl    %edi, %eax
ret
```

The `a ^= b` part responds to the `xorl` line, which, as you can see, is a single instruction. So gcc did not create and then assign a new variable, but just left the operation directly to the CPU.

Note that you should look at this purely because you find it interesting. From a performance point of view, you should *not* care about such things and leave it to your compiler. It is pretty good in optimizing this stuff, so focus your time and knowledge on writing correct and readable code!

Answer (score 2):

Waht happens here is the following:

```
read a
read b
xor the previously variables
store result in a
```

Variables are a high level construct used in most programming languages (but not all). There is no variable created here.

Variables are not identical to memory. When the code above is executed on a CPU, the CPU has to load the operands from ram, if it is not already stored in a register. Weteher or not the input or output of such an oprtation is stored in RAM (aka "memory") or registers depends on the previous and the following operations.

So in short: No variables, data is most liekly copied before it is used, but not necessarily stored in RAM.

Comment: Which programming language doesn't have a concept of variables?

Answer (score 1):

It probably happens in one of the processor's general purpose registers, not in memory but it depends on a lot of factors: CPU architecture, compiler optimization flags, surrounding code.

A possible scenario could be:

- load the value of `a` into a register (let's say `eax` f.e.);
- load the value of `b` into another register (let's say `ebx`);
- xor the values stored in the two registers, the result goes to one of them (`eax`, f.e.);
- store the value from the `eax` register into memory, at the address of `a`.

The variables `a` and `b` themselves might not get a place in memory and spend their lives only in processor registers if they are local variables initialized with constant values, they have short lifespans and the compiler decides it's a waste of time and memory to store them here just to ignore and discard them several instructions later (when the function returns).

In extreme cases, the presented code might not generate CPU instructions at all, if `a` is a local variable and the value of `a` is not used after the assignment, f.e.